# What Resharper setting controls alignment of named call arguments in C#?

Tags: resharper

I got careless and broke it while fiddling.  I don't know what I did.  Cannot get it back.  So this call which used to line up so nicely...

```
new ExportCsvOptions
(
    directory      : new DirectoryInfo(dir!),
    writer         : new StreamWriter(dlg.FileName, false, encoding),
    profileOutputs : allOutputs.Where(o => o.PropType == PropType.Profile).ToList()
);
```

... now shows up like this, even after manually formatting.

```
new ExportCsvOptions
(
    directory : new DirectoryInfo(dir!),
    writer : new StreamWriter(dlg.FileName, false, encoding),
    profileOutputs : allOutputs.Where(o => o.PropType == PropType.Profile).ToList()
);
```

My efforts to fix it have been limited to just this section

***Code Editing >> C# >> Formatting Style >> Tabs Indents and Alignment >> Align Multiline Constructs***

I have individually toggled the following checkboxes with no effect

- *Method Parameters*
- *Call Arguments by '('*
- *Call Arguments*

Also, on that same page I have every single checkbox checked in  "Align Similar Code in Columns"  I've tried unchecking a few of them there.  No effect.

I should add that that initializer blocks do continue to line up perfectly. So if I create the same object but just initialize the properties *after* the default constructor, they look great.

```
new ExportCsvOptions
{
    Directory      = new DirectoryInfo(dir!),
    Writer         = new StreamWriter(dlg.FileName, false, encoding),
    ProfileOutputs = allOutputs.Where(o => o.PropType == PropType.Profile).ToList()
};
```

Also I am using the latest 2022.3.2 version